# If $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, where $p\in[1,\infty]$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, where $p\in[1,\infty]$, must it follow that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$?

My proof thus far is:

> Suppose, for contradiction, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L > 0$. Then there exists $M>0$ such that
> $$
> x > M \quad\Rightarrow\quad \left|f(x)\right| >\frac{L}{2}
> $$
> Then
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|f(x)\right|^p\,dx 
> &= \int_{-\infty}^M \left|f(x)\right|^p\,dx + \int_{M}^\infty \left|f(x)\right|^p\,dx \\
> &> \int_{-\infty}^M \left|f(x)\right|^p\,dx + \left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^p(\infty-M) \\
> &> \infty
> \end{align*}
> Since $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, this leads to a contradiction.

Two things about this proof attempt worries me: (1) I did not use the condition that $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and (2) I began with an (implicit) assumption that the limit exists.

Is the condition $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ necessary to establish this fact? Also, how can we rigorously prove the existence of this limit?

Comment: Hint: The negation of the statement "$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$" is not "$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq0$".

Comment: From what I understand, the negation is that either (a) there exists a sequence $x_n\to\infty$ such that $f(x_n)$ diverges, or (b) there exists two sequence $x_n\to\infty$ and $y_n\to\infty$ such that $f(x_n)\to L$ and $f(y_n)\to M$ and $L\neq M$, or (c) $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$. Did I get this right? If so, I have no idea how (a) and (b) will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: Holder's inequality shows that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\int_x^y f'(t)\,dt|\le||f'||_q|x-y|^{1/q'}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How do we salvage the case where $q=1$ since $|f(x)-f(y)|\le ||f'||_1$ does not imply uniform continuity?

Comment: Hint: The cases (a), (b) and (c) can be summarized to: "There exists a sequence $x_n\to\infty$ such that $f(x_n)\not\to0$".

Comment: True, if $q=1$ then Holder doesn't help. But as you note the point is to get uniform continuity, and that's immediate from the fact that an $L^1$ function is uniformly integrable: If $g\in L^1(\mu)$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(E)<\delta$ implies $\int_E|g|\,d\mu<\epsilon$. (Hint: wlog $g$ is a simple function...)